# How to bring user-control to front from another user-control by c#

Tags: c#

I need to "bring To Front" user-control 2 when i press on a button in user-control 1 .
I search about it in the internet and find answers in some places but i didn't understand it well .
I'm trying to make an object like this .

```
usercontrol1 U1 = new usercontrol1();
U1.bringtofront();
```

It is not working with me .
can anyone tell my how to do this in a simple way .

Comment: You have to do this the right way, raise an event instead.  The form class has no trouble finding that other control so it can subscribe the event and call its BringToFront method.

Comment: could you explain more or give me a topic to search about , please .

Comment: Surely you need to stop searching and start studying.  Any decent introductory winforms book or non-trivial tutorial tells you how to create your own events with the *event* keyword.

Comment: If that's your actual code, then that UserControl isn't the one that's on the form.